# Where is btrfs partition/device info stored in Opensuse

Tags: linux, opensuse, btrfs

I am a Linux newbie running Opensuse. When I run

```
btrfs fi show
```

it shows that I have a device missing. I've tried to manually remove the missing device, but I can only mount my btrfs with read only permissions. I'd like to try and manually remove the missing device with a hex editor.

Where is the device info stored in opensuse? My /proc is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have some kind of raid setup? `btrfs device remove device /path` should remove the disk. Depending on raid level, you might need to rebalance and decrease number of replicas. You can try to use `degraded` mount option to access the device. In general after fidling with a raid it is a good idea to run `btrfs device scan --all` to update the mappings.

Comment: I can mount with the degraded option but the OS ignores my rw instruction and mounts as ro. Is there any way I can force a writeable mount?

Comment: You should first fix your raid - remove the failed drive or decrease the raid level via rebalance.